# Values stored in array is undefined

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to save the ids of input fields that were left blank in an html form using an array called `emptyFields` like this

```
var emptyFields = [];
    $("input").each(function(){
        if( $(this).val() === ''){
            emptyFields.push($(this).attr('id'));                       
    }
```

But when I try to use this array (see below) to access the empty fields, I'm getting an `undefined` warning in Chrome's debugging. Where did I go wrong?

```
for(var i = 0; i < emptyFields.length; i++){
            $("input").attr(emptyFields[i]).val("?");
            // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you already pushed an array of ids so you can select the input with its ID

```
for(var i = 0; i < emptyFields.length; i++){
            $("input#"+emptyFields[i]).val("?");
            // do stuff
}
```